# How to store array of data as a whole using shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an array of string, size 100. I have entered data in this string array. Now, I want to store this array of string using `SharedPreferences`.

So my question is that, is it possible to store the entire array of string instead of storing each string individually using `SharedPreferences`. If so, how that can be done.

The code I have written is used to store data
individually using the loop. But I want to store the entire string array without using the loop.

**Code I have written for storing individually is**

```
SharedPreferences preferencesWrite  = c.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = preferencesWrite.edit();

for(int i=0; i< 100; i++)
{
    editor.putString("dtHistory" + Integer.toString(i), m_dtHistory[i];

}
editor.commit();
```

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981233/android-arraylist-of-custom-objects-save-to-sharedpreferences-serializable/34763035#34763035

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences only allow saving single items per entry - this limitation is enforced so that users can only store, as the name suggests, "preferences" - a flag, a string, a number, and so on. This is to eliminate the unnecessary use of an sqlite database for trivial items.

There is, however, a new method for sharedPreferences (API 11) that allows you to store a set of strings. It's called `putStringSet` and you can check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

Comment: Using shared preferences i am storing only single item only that is note count and it is number. The string i have stored using file

Answer (score 0):

**Yes it,s Possible to Store array in form of String**

you should do something like this :

```
    SharedPreferences preferencesWrite  = c.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = preferencesWrite.edit();

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     ArrayList<ModelClass>favorites = new ArrayList<>();

     String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
     editor.putString("your sharedPref NTT", jsonFavorites);
     editor.apply();
```