# Android ArrayList of custom objects - Save to SharedPreferences - Serializable?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, serializable

I have an ArrayList of an object. The object contains the types 'Bitmap' and 'String' and then just getters and setters for both. First of all is Bitmap serializable?

How would I go about serializing this to store it in SharedPreferences? I have seen many people ask a similar question but none seem to give a good answer. I would prefer some code examples if at all possible.

If bitmap is not serializable then how do I go about storing this ArrayList?

Comment: the drawback of SharedPreferences is that you cannot store objects in it so its not possible to store object :(

Comment: To serialize it, you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5954641/752320). I don't know how that helps with `SharedPreferences`, though, since you can't just store serialized objects there. Maybe you're thinking of a `Bundle`?

Comment: yes you can save. Check my answer.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Yes, you can save your composite object in shared preferences. Let's say..

```
 Student mStudentObject = new Student();
 SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
 Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(mStudentObject);
 prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

..and now you can retrieve your object as:

```
 SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
             .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getApplicationContext());
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = appSharedPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
 Student mStudentObject = gson.fromJson(json, Student.class);
```

For more information, click [here.](http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2011/07/store-and-get-object-in-android-shared.html)

If you want to get back an `ArrayList` of any type object e.g. `Student`, then use:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}.getType();
List<Student> students = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: How to put JSON array name when storing it into prefs?

Comment: What did you mean? please elaborate your question.?

Comment: This code does not work if you want to save an ARRAYLIST

Comment: @Bhavik Metha , Above written code is not for Arraylists, above code is just example. If you want to get back Array List of type any any object e.d student, then us:
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>(){}.getType();
List<Student> students= gson.fromJson(json, type);

Comment: How can I update this list? Is there any way that can I update this list?

Answer (score 124):

The answer above works, but not for list:

For saving list of objects do like this:

```
List<Cars> cars= new ArrayList<Cars>();
    cars.add(a);
    cars.add(b);
    cars.add(c);
    cars.add(d);

    gson = new Gson();
    String jsonCars = gson.toJson(cars);
    Log.d("TAG","jsonCars = " + jsonCars);
```

Read the json object:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Cars>>(){}.getType();
List<Cars> carsList = gson.fromJson(jsonCars, type);
```

Comment: What is the package of `Type` here?

Comment: import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Comment: What if I use wildcards something like:
    `Type type = new TypeToken<List<?>>(){}.getType();`

As a result I am getting a LinkedTreeMap and this is the definition of my method:
    `public static  List<?> getList(String json) {`

Answer (score 25):

For me it worked like this :

Put values in SharedPreferances :

```
String key = "Key";
ArrayList<ModelClass> ModelArrayList=new ArrayList();

SharedPreferences shref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
shref = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ModelArrayList);

editor = shref.edit();
editor.remove(key).commit();
editor.putString(key, json);
editor.commit();
```

To get values from SharedPreferances :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String response=shref.getString(key , "");
ArrayList<ModelClass> lstArrayList = gson.fromJson(response, 
    new TypeToken<List<ModelClass>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 16):

For Save:

```
public static void saveSharedPreferencesLogList(Context context, List<PhoneCallLog> callLog) {
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.CALL_HISTORY_RC, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(callLog);
    prefsEditor.putString("myJson", json);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

For load:

```
public static List<PhoneCallLog> loadSharedPreferencesLogList(Context context) {
    List<PhoneCallLog> callLog = new ArrayList<PhoneCallLog>();
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.CALL_HISTORY_RC, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("myJson", "");
    if (json.isEmpty()) {
        callLog = new ArrayList<PhoneCallLog>();
    } else {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<PhoneCallLog>>() {
        }.getType();
        callLog = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
    return callLog;
}
```

PhoneCallLog is my custom object's name. (Contains String, long and boolean values)

Comment: Shouldn't we use `apply` instead of `commit` ?

Comment: Where we need to place those method calls?

Answer (score 3):

Mete' example above worked like a charm.
Here is a **Kotlin** example

```
private var prefs: SharedPreferences = context?.getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    ?: error("err")
private val gson = Gson()
```

save

```
fun saveObjectToArrayList(yourObject: YourObject) {
    val bookmarks = fetchArrayList()
    bookmarks.add(0, yourObject)
    val prefsEditor = prefs.edit()

    val json = gson.toJson(bookmarks)
    prefsEditor.putString("your_key", json)
    prefsEditor.apply()
}
```

read

```
fun fetchArrayList(): ArrayList<YourObject> {
    val yourArrayList: ArrayList<YourObject>
    val json = prefs.getString("your_key", "")

    yourArrayList = when {
        json.isNullOrEmpty() -> ArrayList()
        else -> gson.fromJson(json, object : TypeToken<List<Feed>>() {}.type)
    }

    return yourArrayList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The kotlin implementation with `Gson`, extending @SpyZips's answer,

**Serializing to JSON**

```
val jsonCars: String = Gson().toJson(cars);
```

**Deserializing to back to list of objs**

```
val type = object: TypeToken<List<Car>>(){}.type
val carsList: List<Car> = Gson().fromJson(jsonCars, type)
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution**

Don't worry you can follow my code.I am using own custom class of sharedPreference for holding anytype of List in sharedPreference.

```java
public class AuthPreference {
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "MY_PREFERENCES";
    private static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
    private static AuthPreference pref;
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPreference;
    private final SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits")
    public AuthPreference(Context context) {
        sharedPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, MODE);
        editor = sharedPreference.edit();
    }

    public void clear() {
        editor.clear().commit();

    }

    //Here  save your api responce like YourModel arraylist

    public void saveDataResponce(ArrayList<YourModel> model_, String key) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreference.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(model_);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();
    }

//Here we get our api responce like YourModel arraylist.Using key value when you want to define.

    public ArrayList<YourModel> getDataResponce(String key) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreference.getString(key, null);
        Type type_ = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourModel>>() {
        }.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use below

```
public static String MyClassListToJsonString(List<MyClassEntry> myMyClassList){
    Gson myGson = new Gson();
    return myGson.toJson(myMyClassList);
}

public static List<MyClass> JsonStringToDepositList(String jsonString){
    Gson myGson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<MyClassEntry>>(){}.getType();
    return myGson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
}
```