# how to save pnr status result to offline

Tags: android, json

Hello everyone I'm getting pnr status using json parsing. I'm fine with this but now I want to save result to offline means when the user once got pnr status using his pnr number once he click on save button then the result should save to offline so that he can see the status without internet. Please anyone help me. Sorry for my english. Thank you.

Comment: you can use shared preference or sqlite for that.

Comment: thank you I used shared preference to save json data. but it always displaying last searched pnr number result.

Comment: Can you please add the code you used to get the PNR status

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this.

Store your Data in SharedPreference,

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("PNR_STATUS", "value");
editor.commit();
```

Get Data,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String pnStatus = prefs.getString("PNR_STATUS", "default_value");
```

if you want to maintain list of all previous pnr status, you can maintain list of all pnr status in Arraylist and retrieve it when needed.

for store and retrieve arraylist in sharedPrefrences you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011927/1992254)

Comment: thank you I used shared preference to save json data. but it always displaying last searched pnr number result only

Comment: would you like to get all previos pnr status ?

Comment: yes I am saving searched PNRs in listview. So when I click any PNR number from listview it should get selected PNR number result in offline.

Comment: for that you can maintain the arraylist of all the searched pnr status and store that array in SharedPreferences.. and retrieve that stored array list from SharedPreferences and you can display it when internet is not available. refer link in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks to all. I have used database to store all pnr values and retrieved while fetching result

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the listed [ORM](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/) .

Create a table with Time as a primary and PNR status with some user related information.