# Unable to save SharedPreferences using Gson on ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist, gson, sharedpreferences

I am trying the solution in the top answer here: [Android ArrayList of custom objects - Save to SharedPreferences - Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981233/android-arraylist-of-custom-objects-save-to-sharedpreferences-serializable)

I am trying to save to SharedPreferences an ArrayList of custom objects.

```
SharedPreferences appSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(baseApplication);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(masterPinList);
prefsEditor.putString("masterPinList", json);
prefsEditor.apply();
```

`masterPinList` is an ArrayList of custom objects (`Pin`).

The error is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Can not make a java.lang.reflect.Method constructor accessible
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
String json = gson.toJson(masterPinList);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Show the code for `Pin`

Comment: Pin has references to the application and other custom objects. Based on answer below, and after testing with another custom object, I found that it would be easier to make a Pin object without references to contexts or other custom objects in the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add an empty constructor to the class as this will  used to set values.

```
public className() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your object serializable ? It could be the problem. Here is a example class

```
public class PlanDateObject {

@SerializedName("DateList")
private List<String> dateList;
@SerializedName("PlanList")
private List<Plan> planList;

public List<String> getDateList() {
    return dateList;
}

public void setDateList(List<String> dateList) {
    this.dateList = dateList;
}

public List<Plan> getPlanList() {
    return planList;
}

public void setPlanList(List<Plan> planList) {
    this.planList = planList;
}
```

}

Comment: Would every other custom object referenced by this object also need to be serializable, because just making Pin serializable did not not work?

Comment: Yes. I tested your code with this class and it worked